# Cakephp 2.1 and Jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, cakephp, jquery

**Mission:**

Implement autocomplete of departments(saved in departments table) in employee form field called department.
A user enters a few spellings of department name
That brings up list of the names matching departments 
The user select one and that's it.

**Platforms**

1. CakePhp 2.1
2. Jquery UI Autocomplete(part of Jquery UI library version 1.8.18)

**Database Model**

Emplyee (id, first_name,last_name,department_id)
department(id,name)

so in my add.ctp file ajax call is something like

```
      $( "#auto_complete" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url:  "/employees/showDepartment",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    alert("success--");
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    //alert(item);
                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.id
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
```

i have a action in my EmployeeController called show_depatment()

```
    public function getAddress() {
        $this->autoRender = false;// I do not want to make view against this  action. 
        $this->log($this->params->query['name_startsWith'] , 'debug');
        $str = $this->params->query['name_startsWith'];
        $this->log($str, 'debug');
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $departments = $this->Employee->Department->find('all', array( 'recursive' => -1,
            'conditions'=>array('Department.name LIKE'=>$str.'%'),
   'fields'=>array('name', 'id')));
        //$this->set('departments',$departments);
        $this->log($departments, 'debug');
        echo json_encode($departments);
}
```

I dont want show_department action to have any view so i have made **$this->autoRender = false;**

but it is not working as expected.

when i debug the response using firebug in response and HTLM section it shows

```
           [{"Department":{"name":"Accounting","id":"4"}}] // when i type "acc" in input field
```

Question

1. How to make it to display in form field.
2. echo json_encode($departments); is it right method of sending response in json format?
3. when i alert in sucess part of ajax call (alert(item);) it gives error as "undefined"

Answer (score 2):

i'm friend of fat Model and skinny Controller so my Controller action looks like this

```
public function getAddress()
{
    if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        Configure::write('debug', 0);
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->autoRender = false;
        echo json_encode($this->Employee->Department->getAddress($this->params['url']['term']));
        exit;
    }
}
```

and my Department model method:

```
public function getAddress($str)
{

    $rs = array();
    $search =  $this->find('all', array( 
        'recursive' => -1,
        'conditions'=>array('Department.name LIKE'=>$str.'%'),
        'fields'=>array('name', 'id')
    ));


    if (!empty($search))
    {
        //the jquery ui autocomplete requires object with label/value  so we need to traverse the query results and create required array 

        foreach ($search as $key => $val)
        {
            $rs[] = array('label' => $val['Department']['name'], 
              'value' => $val['Department']['id']);
        }
    }
    return $rs;
}
```

and finaly my view entry is like this:

```
$( "#auto_complete" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var term = request.term;
        if ( term in cache ) {
            response( cache[ term ] );
            return;
        }

        lastXhr = $.getJSON( "/employees/showDepartment", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
            cache[ term ] = data;
            if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
                response( data );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

hope this helps.